# Maven hangs when taking input via Scanner

Tags: java, maven, java.util.scanner

I am designing an app that has to run with cmd using command  `mvn clean package`. It should take user input using Scanner. When I run the program with mvn everything works until Scanner.next() is executed, then everything just hangs and I have to close app. But when I run it with Junit through eclipse everything works fine.

```
  public void testRemoveWordsWithMoreVowelsFromConsole() {
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
  String textFromConsole = scanner.nextLine();

  assertEquals(wordsWithMoreVowelsRemoved,
      TextFormatting.removeWordsWithMoreVowels(textFromConsole));
}}
```

if you know any alternatives for inputting data via cmd I'll appreciate it. Thanks in advance!
Here is my Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>ua.lviv.iot.java_lab6</groupId>
<artifactId>javaLab6</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>javaLab6</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.12.2</version>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- overwrite dependency on spotbugs if you want to specify the version 
                    of spotbugs -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spotbugs</artifactId>
                    <version>4.0.0-RC3</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- plugin> <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId> <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
            <version>0.8.2</version> </plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.13.0</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.12.2</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <configLocation>google_checks.xml</configLocation>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Maven has nothing to do with runtime. There is possibly a bug in your code.

Comment: Within the test you are trying to get input from console (System.in) this of course blocks. Why do you need to use `scanner.nextLine();`?

Comment: `scanner.nextLine()` is waiting for your input. Enter some value or simply press `Enter` to proceed.